# Display random name with repeated one word within the array

Tags: php, arrays, random

What i am trying to acheve here is to display a random list of names but with the exemption of a few postions

below is the code i am trying to get to work and trying to display a list of names apart from 2 positions which i am trying to display the same title but in both postions.

```
<?php
$input = array("name1", "name2", "name3", "name4", "name5", "name6", "name7", "name8", "name9", "name10");
$same = array("same1", "same2", "same3", "same4", "same5", "same6", "same7", "same8", "same9", "same10");
$rand_keys = array_rand($input, 10);
$samerand_keys = array_rand($input, 1);
echo $input[$rand_keys[0]] . "\n<br>";
echo $input[$rand_keys[1]] . "\n<br>";
echo $same[$samerand_keys[1]] . "\n<br>";
echo $input[$rand_keys[3]] . "\n<br>";
echo $input[$rand_keys[4]] . "\n<br>";
echo $input[$rand_keys[5]] . "\n<br>";
echo $same[$samerand_keys[1]] . "\n<br>";
echo $input[$rand_keys[7]] . "\n<br>";
echo $input[$rand_keys[8]] . "\n<br>";
echo $input[$rand_keys[9]] . "\n<br>";
echo $input[$rand_keys[10]] . "\n<br>";
?>
```

This displays the random list and shows the random list apart from the 2 places of the same answer.

I am sorry this is hard to explain i hope you understand what i am trying to achieve also any suggestions on the title of this question would be great

---

Output of the results i am trying to achieve.

dave (random name)

simon (random name)

harry (random name)

**KELLY** (random title but the same)

marry (random name)

joe (random name)

**KELLY** (random title but the same)

bob (random name)

Comment: So you want results like `name1 => same4` but not `name6 => same6`?

Comment: @BeatAlex i have updated the question, i hope it helps

Comment: Where does the "random title" comes from? And what do u mean with "the same"?

Comment: `When picking only one entry, array_rand() returns the key for a random entry.`

Comment: the random title comes from the array "same" so if the title was "ThatMSG" this would repeat in the positions i require.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Im not to sure why you are trying to use two arrays, you can get your results from just one just use a single one.

```
<?php
$input = array("name1", "name2", "name3", "name4", "name5", "name6", "name7", "name8", "name9", "name11", "name10");
$rand_keys = array_rand($input, 11);
echo $input[$rand_keys[1]] . "\n<br>";
echo $input[$rand_keys[2]] . "\n<br>";
echo $input[$rand_keys[3]] . "\n<br>";
echo $input[$rand_keys[0]] . "\n<br>";
echo $input[$rand_keys[5]] . "\n<br>";
echo $input[$rand_keys[6]] . "\n<br>";
echo $input[$rand_keys[7]] . "\n<br>";
echo $input[$rand_keys[0]] . "\n<br>";
echo $input[$rand_keys[9]] . "\n<br>";
echo $input[$rand_keys[10]] . "\n<br>";
?>
```

In the positions You want the same name I have placed a **0**